# writing millions of records in XML asynch with file operation c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have requirement to write/feed live records in xml file on server.

I have written code to insert/update xml file in asynch. PFB code snap, and working fine on local.
But in production when the no. of records, increased, the file gets stuck and not getting completed with correct tag.

```
public static async Task InsertPersonDetailsXMLSync(Stream stream, SavePersonDetailsInput objInput)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
    xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
    xmlWriterSettings.Async = true;
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter =  XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        await xmlWriter.WriteStartDocumentAsync();
        await xmlWriter.WriteStartElementAsync(null,"ArrayOfPersonDetailsInput",null);
        await xmlWriter.WriteStartElementAsync(null,"PersonDetailsInput",null);
        await xmlWriter.WriteElementStringAsync(null,"PersonName",null, objInput.PersonName);
        await xmlWriter.WriteElementStringAsync(null,"UpdatedDate",null, DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
        await xmlWriter.WriteEndElementAsync();
        await xmlWriter.FlushAsync();
        xmlWriter.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
}

public static async Task UpdatePersonDetailsXMLSync(string file, SavePersonDetailsInput objInput)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(file);
        XElement root = xDocument.Element("ArrayOfPersonDetailsInput");
        IEnumerable<XElement> rows = root.Descendants("PersonDetailsInput");
        XElement firstRow = rows.First();          
        firstRow.AddBeforeSelf(
        new XElement("PersonDetailsInput",
        new XAttribute("PersonName", PersonName),
        new XElement("UpdatedDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))));            
        xDocument.Save(file);
    });
}
```

When file get larger, like after 17MB to 18MB (or more than million records), it is getting stuck as the file not update correctly in thread and when we open that file, the end tag were not completed successfully.

below is file stuck file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPersonDetailsInput>
  <PersonDetailsInput>
    <PersonName>ABCD</PersonName>
    <UpdatedDate>08-28-2019 11:41:18</UpdatedDate>
  </PersonDetailsInput>
   <PersonDetailsInput>
    <PersonName>PQRS</PersonName>
    <UpdatedDate>08-28-2019 11:41:10</UpdatedDate>
  </PersonDetailsInput>
 '
'
100000 PersonDetailsInput nodes here.last node in file having problem while writing large file.
'
'
<PersonDetailsInput>
    <PersonName>PQRS</Pers
```

The expected output is, it should always complete node and its end tag  correctly while saving data with `async`.

Comment: Just curious; why are you not using a database?

Comment: @Silvermind , we have more elements in this PersonDetailsInput node , which later required processed and feed in DB with separate process.

Comment: Then I would have created an intermediate db. The problem I see is that it's hard to handle concurrent reads and writes to the files. And I suspect there lies your problem.

Comment: Exactly!!! Normal XML is well formed where there is a a single node at the root.  Lots of applications use Xml Format that is not well formed with an array at the root (like feeds and log files).  So in Net Library the only way of reading these files is to used XmlReader with the option "settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;".  The other choice is to wrap the xml text in a new root : <root> old xml string </root>

Comment: A self-mutating XML file? Everything about that idea is bad. Instead of trying to do your data manipulation in-line, split the process into separate steps: (1) read in the data (2) process/filter it (3) write the result to an XML file (which can be parallelised to write in chunks).

Comment: @Silvermind,in this scenario here I have more 15 elements inside each separate PersonDetailsInput node. and data base transaction again gets slow for this process and make sql stack full. So , we are here capturing information in xml file and by scheduling job we are processing this file next day.

Comment: @jdweng, I can not create multiple root node for each new record, as we have subsequent processes designed on it.Also, How to set settings.ConformanceLevel  in my UpdatePersonDetailsXMLSync method where I don't have XMLSetting.

Comment: You create XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings().  The when you do a XmlReader.Create(filename, settings)

Comment: @IanKemp , Here my first step is to save all incoming data to XML. And in particular this scenario when file is getting larger it is failing.

Comment: Sorry for late post. I have removed "await Task.Run(() =>" block from update method and it solved my issue at that time.